# Scrapy: How to stop requesting in case of 302?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy 2.4 to crawl specific pages from a start_urls list. Each of those URLs has persumably 6 result pages, so I request them all.

In some cases however there is only 1 result page and all other paginated pages return a 302 to pn=1. In this case I do not want to follow that 302 nor do I want to continue looking for page 3,4,5,6 but rather continue to the next URL in the list.

How to exit (continue) this for loop in case of a 302/301 and how to not follow that 302?

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        for i in range(1,7): # 6 pages
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url + f'&pn={str(i)}'
            )

def parse(self, request):

    # parse page
    ...

    # recognize no pagination and somehow exit the for loop
    if not response.xpath('//regex'): 
        # ... continue somehow instead of going to page 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem of your approach is that from `start_requests` we can't know for ahead how many valid pages exists.

Common approach for this type of cases 
is to schedule requests one by one in this way istead of loop:

```py
class somespider(scrapy.Spider):
...
    def start_requests(self):
        ...
        for u in self.start_urls:
            # schedule only first page of each "query"
            yield scrapy.Request(url=u+'&pn=1', callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        r_url, page_number = response.url.split("&pn=")
        page_number = int(page_number)
        ....
        if next_page_exists:
            yield scrapy.Request(
            url = f'{r_url}&pn={str(page_number+1)}',
            callback = self.parse)
       else:
           # something else
           ...
```

Comment: I undertand, however this results in my root cause problem I had: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65423455/how-to-yield-in-scrapy-without-a-request
Your solution looks very similar to my first approach that led to this work around resulting in this problem.

Comment: Yes. I see. `example.html` and `example.thml?pn=1` can have the same output, hovewer this implementation doesn't have request for `example.html` and It will not send requests to the same page twice.

Comment: Great! This not only works, but also made me understand it better how Scrapy works so I could improve the algo even further. Thank you!